# Android Save RSA Private and Public Key

Tags: java, android, rsa, android-keystore

I need to save my RSA private and public key. Here I create it.

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(1024);
KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
publicKey = kp.getPublic();
privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
```

Now I want to use both keys the next time. So they should be stored on the device.

```
        byte[] publicKeyBytes = publicKey.getEncoded();
        byte[] privateKeyBytes = privateKey.getEncoded();
```

So I can get the Byte Arrays and then I save them as a text file.
Then the next time i read it and convert it back to the byte Array.

Now my question: How can i convert a byte array back to a key?

This does not really work:

```
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes);
    publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);
    spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
    privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(spec);
```

On LogCat, this is going to be display:

> Must use RSAPublicKeySpec or PKCS8EncodedKeySpec; was
>   java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec

Any ideas whats wrong with this code?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` for the private key.

`RSAPublicKeySpec` for the public key, instead of `X509EncodedKeySpec` for both.

Please also note that saving keys to a text file might not be the most secure idea. Android provides a nice [KeyStore Api](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html), which is easy to use.

Comment: Although I haven't verified it I believe `X509EncodedKeySpec` for the public key is correct.

Comment: Thank you jHilscher, not it workes! - And yes GregS i use now X509EncodedKeySpec for the public key, and PKCS8EncodedKeySpec for the private key.

Comment: Hi. Can you provide the code for initialization for RSAPublicKeySpec. Having trouble looking into it in net

Answer (score -2):

You try encode the keys in Base64 and stored like a String, when you retrieved only need decoded the keys from Base64 to Byte arrays.